# how to find contact's phone number with iOS formatting though Phonegap?

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

So i'm having trouble trying to search contacts using Cordova Phonegap for phone numbers that contain area code and/or country code on an IOS device.

For example: i have a contact with # 1 (718) 555-5555. When i display that contacts info (through phone gap using contacts.find()) the phone number string shows up as "1 (718) 555-5555". But if i try to search using "1 (718) 555-5555", Phonegap cannot find it.

Numbers without country code and area code can be found such as "555-5555".

How exactly are phone numbers stored in iOS that contain Area code and/or Country Code?

```
function findContact(num) {

if (!navigator.contacts) {
    console.log("Contacts API not supported");
    return;
}

var options = new ContactFindOptions();
options.filter = num;
options.multiple = true;
var fields = ["phoneNumbers"];

navigator.contacts.find(fields, function(contacts) {
                        if (contacts.length == 0) {
                        console.log('Contact not found, num ' + num);
                        }
                        else {
                        console.log('Found ' + contacts.length + ' contacts w/num: ' + num);
                        }
                        }, function(error){}, options);    

}
```

*** edit *** 
So i narrowed the issue to CDVContact.m in the cordova contacts plugin. in the testMultiValueStrings method

```
 valueArray = [self valuesForProperty:propId inRecord:self.record];  

if (valueArray) { 
NSString* valuesAsString = [valueArray componentsJoinedByString:@" "]; 
NSPredicate* containPred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@", testValue]; 
bFound = [containPred evaluateWithObject:valuesAsString]; }
```

The valuesAsString does show up correctly in a format such as @"1 (555) 555-5555" and the testValue string is identical but bFound still evaluates to NO.

Maybe there's some metadata associated with the valueArray causing the bug?

Answer (score -1):

So i figured out that spaces in iOS phone numbers are non blocking spaces i.e. &nbsp. Have to declare any spaces in the search string with String.fromCharCode(160).